# Output Segy attributes in CSV

Tags: python, csv

I would like to convert Segy to CSV then edit in CSV and convert CSV to Segy back.

I used trace headers to dataframe from segyio python [example](https://github.com/equinor/segyio/blob/master/python/examples/trace_headers_to_dataframe.py).
I then convert the dataframe to CSV.

When I compared the output .csv from dataframe to the output from [online converter](https://mygeodata.cloud/converter/segy-to-csv), dataframe output lacks a column called SAMPLE_ARRAY each cell of which contain multiple data

[My_Segy](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VMXbt4tdOxpGaKKZLh6nUltjzb8RkJhp/view?usp=sharing)

[Dataframe_output](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1935N8kF9bJj3db68S6ObQK3gEeRY7hDl/view?usp=sharing)

[OnlineConverter_output](https://drive.google.com/file/d/19o5fRDzYVbMZv_HWbqlxGmeyPRpZYJ92/view?usp=sharing)

```
import segyio
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import sys
def main():
    filename = 'Seis.sgy'

    # Open file
    with segyio.open(filename, ignore_geometry=True) as f:
    # Get all header keys:
        header_keys = segyio.tracefield.keys
        # Initialize df with trace id as index and headers as columns
        trace_headers = pd.DataFrame(index=range(1, f.tracecount+1),
                                 columns=header_keys.keys())
        # Fill dataframe with all trace headers values
        for k, v in header_keys.items():
            trace_headers[k] = f.attributes(v)[:]
    print(trace_headers.head())
    trace_headers.to_csv('out.csv')
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: While I understand you don''t want to post everything, it still is important to post the code inline, to make sure the post stays intact when other source providers may go down. Please provide a minimal set to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @StarShine Please Find code used to produce .csv attached now

Comment: Hi @HannaNabil found any solution to this issue